# Pass variable from another page

Tags: php, html

I can't pass the variable to another page using session and i don't know what is the error here. Can someone help me? and clues on how to use the session? i want to pass the variable username to another page.

here is the html code. this is my login page where the variable is coming from.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
  <form class="logform" action="" method="post">
    <p class="title">Admin Login</p>
    <input type="user" name="uname" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="password" name ="pword" placeholder="Password" />
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
    <button type="submit" value="login" name="login">
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>

<?php
session_start();

include_once("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user = $_POST["uname"];
  $password = $_POST["pword"];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
    $select_user="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username ='$user' AND password ='$password'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user > 0){
    $_SESSION['uname'] = $username;
        header('location:admin.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
?>
```

here is the admin page.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $username; ?>!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: admin page is failing you as is your login page and don't go live with this, not with that text password storage

Comment: @Fred why? can you give me idea, why?

Comment: @Fred can you give me tips?

Comment: ask David; he put in an answer below

Comment: Ye im being forwareded to the admin page. and when i tried the answer below i can see the "Weclome,!" But the username is blank. Only welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the session value on the first page:

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $username;
```

But you never read it on the second page.  Read the session value:

```
$username = $_SESSION['uname'];
```

---

**Edit:** Come to think of it, you're never even setting the `$username` variable on the *first* page.  Did you mean to use `$user` instead?  Or `$name`?

You can transfer a value via session exactly as you are, but there has to be a value to transfer in the first place.

Comment: hello sir i tried that it's working but the username is blank when on admin page. this is the output "Welcome,!" Username is missing. Blank.

Comment: or he could just use the `$_SESSION['uname']` directly on the next page

Comment: @nethken: What is the value of `$username` on the *first* page?  Looking at the code again, you're never setting that variable at all.  Ever.  You can't print a variable that you never set.

Comment: Im just a newbie sir, sorry.

Comment: Then what variable will i put sir?

Comment: @nethken: Whatever variable you want.  Whatever value you want to put in the session for the next page, set the session value to that variable.  Then on the next page, read the session value that you set.

Comment: Thanks sir :) Im watching a tutorial in youtube and in his admin page there is no session_start and $user = $_SESSION['uname'];.

Answer (score 1):

Where on the admin page have you set `$username = $_SESSION['uname']`? The `$username` variable in the first page is local to that page, it's not a session variable. When you are on the admin page, `$username` is a new variable and is not defined, even though `$_SESSION['uname']` is.

Answer (score 1):

Ok there are two problems here. First off, **$_SESSION['uname']** needs to contain the username which would be **$user** NOT **$username** ($username is undefined). Second, if you want to assign **$_SESSION['uname']** to a variable, then you must do so on the admin page. Below is the code you should use...

**Login Page**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <form class="logform" action="" method="post">
    <p class="title">Admin Login</p>
    <input type="user" name="uname" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
    <input type="password" name ="pword" placeholder="Password" />
    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
    <button type="submit" value="login" name="login">
      <i class="spinner"></i>
      <span class="state">Log in</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>

<?php
session_start();

include_once("connection.php");
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user = $_POST["uname"];
  $password = $_POST["pword"];
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $user);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
    $select_user="SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username ='$user' AND password ='$password'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $select_user);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user > 0){
        $_SESSION['uname'] = $name;
        header('location:admin.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "wrong";
    }
}
?>
```

**Admin Page**

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['uname'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $username; ?>!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```